# How to retrieve a county when giving a mailing address?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to get a JSON response of a county name when I send an http request with a mailing address? Does Google maps have something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) (for JavaScript) or just the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) for anything else (to get over a URL).